# template instantiation issue with complex data types

Tags: c++, templates, numerical-recipes

I have the type of parameters as

```
typedef double DP;
typedef const NRVec<DP> Vec_I_DP; //NRVec is a parametrized template class.
typedef NRVec<DP> Vec_DP, Vec_O_DP, Vec_IO_DP;

xa -> Vec_I_DP(30)
ya -> Vec_I_DP(30)
yp1 -> DP(30)
ypn -> DP(30)
y2 -> Vec_O_DP(30)
```

My function call is

```
NR::spline(xa,          ya,          yp1,          ypn,         y2);
```

And the function declaration is

```
void spline(Vec_I_DP &x, Vec_I_DP &y, const DP yp1, const DP ypn,Vec_O_DP &y2);
```

Can somebody tell me, why I get the following error.

```
1>Hiwi.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl NR::spline(class NRVec<double> const &,class NRVec<double> const &,double,double,class NRVec<double> &)" (?spline@NR@@YAXABV?$NRVec@N@@0NNAAV2@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl smooth_Line(double *,int *,int,int,double *,double *,int,int)" (?smooth_disp_Line@@YAXPANPAHHH00HH@Z)
```

Comment: What are the macros Vec_I_DP and Vec_O_DP?

Comment: The problem seems to be related to linking, not template instantiation. Did you define the function `NR::spline`? Did you include the file in which the function is defined to the project/makefile?

Comment: Where is the function defined?  Are you linking against it?  Please check through this: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using NR2. The newest version is NR3 which defines spline in a class called `Spline_interp`. You should use NR3. For this matter, I will show you an example for using the aforementioned class. Let's say you have five values for `sin(x)` and you can to interpolate these values and acquire the interpolated values, say `sin(x=.25)`. In this example, we know true value, therefore, we can compare the result with the interpolated value. In the following code, I got the interpolated value plus the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "nr3.h"
#include "interp_1d.h" 

int main() {
    VecDoub x(5), y(5);

    //x = 0:0.3:1
    //y = sin(x)

    x[0] = 0.0;
    x[1] = 0.3;
    x[2] = 0.6;
    x[3] = 0.9;

    y[0] = 0.0;
    y[1] = 0.2955;
    y[2] = 0.5646;
    y[3] = 0.7833;

    /**************************************************
        3.3 Cubic Spline Interpolation
        page(120)
    ***************************************************/

    Spline_interp myfunc3(x,y);
    std::cout << "Cubic Spline Interpolation: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "interp value: " << myfunc3.interp(.25)  << "\n" 
              << "  true value: " << sin(0.25)            << "\n" 
              << "       error: " << ( ( sin(0.25) - myfunc3.interp(.25) )/sin(0.25) )*100.0  << "%" << std::endl;


    std::cout << std::setw(25) << std::cout.fill('=') << std::endl; 


    return 0;
}
```

For compilation in Windows from the command prompt,

```
cl /EHsc main.cpp /Fetest.exe /I path\to\NR\code
```

The result is

```
Cubic Spline Interpolation:
interp value: 0.247187
  true value: 0.247404
       error: 0.0876794%
========================
```

The error is very small.

Comment: If you really want to use NR2, notify me so that I can post an answer regarding this matter, however, I highly recommend you to use NR3